# Getting a value from a click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div id="card0">
<div id="card1">
<div id="card2">
<div id="card3">
<div id="card4">
```

I have created a card, deck, and hand "class."
What I would like to do is create an event handler for an array of cards.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    myHand.cards[i] = myDeck.deal();
}
```

I would like to do also in the loop to create event handlers:

```
$("#card"+i).on("click", cardClicked);
function cardClicked() {
    alert(this);
}
```

Is there a way to find out which div was clicked on?  I have tried doing an anonymous function passing event. I have tried with this, but I don't know what else to try.

Comment: or maybe is there a way to associate a div with the card object?

Comment: Your `cardClicked()` would have had `this` referencing what element was accepting the event; try `console.log(this);` instead and have your Javascript console open.

Comment: Your html is invalid `<div id="card0">`.  Also, there are plenty of other answers on SO to help you with this.

Comment: @Dan - The OP added the `<br>` tags mistakenly thinking it was necessary to format the code.

Comment: yeah I know its invalid, thats the only way I knew to write it on here

Comment: Im sorry everything isn't written perfectly, my code works, just I was giving examples so maybe someone could understand and help

Comment: please don't -1 me, I am a beginner.  Everyone has to start somewhere.  Seriously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Just give your event handler a parameter to pass when it is called:

```
function cardClicked(e){
   console.log(e.target.id);
}
```

Note that you should use `console.log()` for debugging, not `alert()`. Logging to the console will show you the actual structure of the element/object/whatever you're logging.

Also, there is a simpler way to attach the listeners:

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){
    $(divs[i]).click(function(e){
        console.log(e.target.id);
    });
}
```

Comment: There isn't an `element.click()` method (I think you mean `element.onclick = function(e){...}`. You're also missing the closing `)` on the incorrect `.click()` method.

Comment: yes I get the target, which is the div, so how do I know which card that is in my card array?  Thats where i am stumped.

Comment: @JaredFarrish You're correct about the closing parenthesis, but `$(element).click(function(){});` exists in jQuery, which the OP has tagged his/her question with (but you're right: I did forget the `$`).

Comment: @PatGrady Ah, you can use `target.id` to get the ID or any of its other properties: I've updated it. I thought that you were just using the `alert()` for debugging.

Comment: I've got a copy of your original code; it was `divs[i].click(function(e){`. That was not jQuery.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Yes, see the end of my last reply.

Comment: that is not my code at all.. divs[i].click(function(e){ ??? I don't know where that came from. and alert is just for debugging.  Also, thank you with id I do get the div id, but again my problem where I am stumped is to associate that with a certain card to change it?

Comment: @PatGrady That's just a simpler way of attaching them: you don't have to use it. `e.target` *gives* you the element: you can use that in the same way you'd use any other element that you've grabbed with `document.getElementById()` or something like that.

Comment: I know but my problem is how do I attach a <div id="card0"> to myHand.cards[0]?

Comment: You don't need `event.target` to get the element, `this` will give you the element.

Comment: @PatGrady I've created a [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/67k06ckL/1): does this do what you're asking?

Comment: this-><div id="card0>  ok so how do I make this === myHand.cards[0]?

Comment: @JaredFarrish That's true, but I was trying to make it clear where it's coming from.

Comment: @PatGrady After the demo runs, check your browser console: `cards` is an array with all of the `div`s.

Comment: so how do i associate the div with the myHand.cards object?  ie, when I click on card0 (div), how do I make myHands.cards[0].isClicked === true

Comment: i don't get why this is so complicated.  Isn't there a way to associate an HTML element with an object in jQuery?

Comment: i could create an event listener for each: $("#card0").on("click", card0Clicked); $("#card1").on("click", card1Clicked), etc.. but would like to use a DRY method, andy ideas?

Comment: myHand is not an array!  it is an object: // Start of Hand Class
function Hand(){
    this.cards = [];
    return this;
}

Hand.prototype.length = function(){
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.cards.length; i++){
        if(this.cards[i] !== null){
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
};

Comment: @PatGrady Exactly. `myHand` is an object with a `cards` array: look at the code in the demo.

Comment: var num = parseInt(event.target.id.substring(event.target.id.length - 1));